# What is the name of a quantity expressed in Tm?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

Consider the quantity defined as a magnetic field times a length is expressed in tesla*meter:

$Bl\ [\mathrm{Tm}]$

that arises for instance in the expression $F=BlI$.

What is the appropriate terminology for this quantity $Bl$?

Answer (score 2):

A common quantity is the magnetic flux, $\int \mathrm dA \, B$. That is measured in $\mathrm{T \, m^2}$.

Your quantity seems to be a linear flux density, so the flux density integrated along a single dimension. That would be a little strange though.

It could also be a line integral, like $\oint \mathrm d\vec l \cdot \vec B$. This is used in Maxwell's equation in Ampère's law. The quantity could be called “magnetic line integral” or so, I do not know a canonical name for it.